# How to extend functions inside webpack bundle after compile?

Tags: webpack, extends

How to extend functions inside webpack bundle after compile?
Does anybody know?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Webpack create one file with functions. I want with javascript prototype extend some of it. But problem is how to extend functions after compile, because Webpack change the original names of functions.

Comment: well you must import it to obtain a reference? Post some code it will be easier to understand what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

From your short question. I believe you are trying to access / extend or to put simply use the function inside a bundled javascript file outside it. There are different ways you could do this.

**Method 1**

If there are multiple such functions you would like to use outside of it, then you have to export the function using:

```
module.exports = {
      yourfunctionName
}
```

And then you have to configure your webpack to treat this as a library. This is how most of the libraries do. Now to access the function outside the bundled file. Simply use your library name (*as configured in webpack*) for e.g, let's say my library name is myLibrary then the code will be:

```
myLibrary.yourFunctionName
```

**Method 2**

if you don't need to export many functions or you are looking for a quick easy answer to this then you can add your functions to window object, which makes it available everywhere.

In your main file (which is going to be bundled) **filename.bundle.js**

```
window.functionName = yourFunction;
```

And wherever you want to access that function outside of bundle

```
window.functionName();
```

It isn't advisable to put the functions in window object, But if you are looking for quick easy fix then method 2 is good for you.